# How to flip the face of a closed 2D curve (similar to normal flip for mesh)?

Tags: bezier-curves

I use Blender 2.69. When I create a closed curve (for example, a circle) and make it 2D with the properties editor, it becomes filled.

Since I work with backface culling on (because of the application of the objects I make), only one of the sides is visible. In the case of a just created circle or a figure imported from SVG, it's the bottom side. In the latter case, it is especially annoying, because the figure appears mirrored.

Is there a simple way to flip the face (similar to flipping the normal for a mesh face) so that it shows on the opposite side of the curve?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can swap the normal of the face by flipping the directions of the curve.

1. Select the curve
2. In edit mode go to *Curve -> Segments -> Switch Direction*. You can also do this via the space menu be searching for "switch direction"

Comment: Thanks! That worked, except I needed to select something first while in edit mode. It's annoying that it can't be done while in object mode, because I have to do it to each polygon imported from SVG, switching back and forth and selecting something for each polygon. Any clue about whether it's possible to do it while in object mode, to be able to do it in bulk?

Comment: You can do that using python. But also maybe you should join all curves together first?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need, scaling -1 in a global direction might work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried that before asking. It flips the face _and_ mirrors the curve, so it is equivalent to rotating 180°, thus not solving the mirror problem.

Comment: You need to restrict the scale to one direction only (e.g. press S; Z; -1 ).

Comment: Yes, this works too. It failed for me because I tried it in edit mode, but in object mode it works, which is an advantage. It has the drawback that applying the scale reverts the effect, though.

Comment: Of cause this is a quick and dirty approach. That is why i wrote "Depending on what you need". For rendering "Front Face" or "Back Face" this should be a sufficient fix thought.